# mistakenly deleted svn remote configuration, what to do?

Tags: git, git-svn

I had git repository set to track a certain svn repository. I periodically updated my master branch to the svn repo:

```
git svn fetch
git rebase git-svn
```

the master branch had no modifications.

Then, I messed up stuff, so I decided to wipe away my local repo, and cloned it again from upstream. Now my local repo lost track of anything svn related. How can set it up again? I'm worried about git not realizing that the master branch has already been rebase up to a certain revision. To make things worse, the URL of the svn repo has changed.

Comment: If you deleted configuration, you may restore it by running "git svn init <new_URL> -s tmp" and copy [svn-remote "svn"] section from tmp/.git/config. Add svn-remote.svn.rewriteRoot=old_URL option to make git-svn understand git-svn-id signatures. Then run "git svn fetch". If I understand the question correctly, this should help.